# Registering a SAML application (without SSO) with WSO2 Identity Server

Tags: java, saml, wso2-identity-server

Am trying to write a Java code which gets application details like app name, description etc from end user and registers the application with the WSO2 Identity Server. Also I need to generate the SAML token for the registered application. It is basic application registration and SAML token generation without SSO and stuff. Am I making sense? if so please lead me to a good approach to solve this problem.

Comment: Your question is not very clear. Do you want to register service provider and do SAML configuration from some client application ?

Comment: SAML configuration through a Java program.

Comment: Yes exactly. I want to register a service provider and do SAML configuration from a Java program.

Comment: What is the version of Identity Server you are planning to use ? 5.1.0 is the latest release.

Comment: Am using 5.1.0 only.

Answer (score 1):

Consume "IdentityApplicationManagementService" createApplication operation.

1. In carbon.xml set  to false.
2. Brows WSDL https://localhost:9443/services/IdentityApplicationManagementService?wsdl
3. Generate necessary stubs
4. Invoke createApplication operation with necessary parameters

Answer (score 0):

If you need to use SAML SSO, you should use IdentitySAMLSSOConfigService also.